# Python Error: Only size one arrays can be converted into python scalars

Tags: python, numpy

I get this error. I should note that in my utility file "funcbarsq" is a function defined as a four vector dot product between another function `funcbar` and itself `funcbar`. Which uses another definition of a four vector dot product. So a four d dot product operation is defined, `funcbar` is defined, and `funcbarsq` is defined as the 4D dot product of `funcbar*funcbar = funcbarsq`.

```
C:\utilityfile in function(x, y, z, q, r, l, m, n)
    116 
    117 def function(x,y,z, q, r, l, m, n):
--> 118     val = np.abs(funcbarsqr/(float(q**2))
    119     return val
    120 

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `q**2` to `float()`. As the error message says, this value (and consequently `q`) should be an array with *only one element*. In your case it is not, and that's where the error comes from.